# Error: System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType'

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I want to delete all Ellipses from a WPF Canvas. I used this method :

```
public void clearCircle()
{
    var circles = cvsSurface.Children.OfType<Ellipse>().ToList();
    foreach (var c in circles)
    {
        cvsSurface.Children.Remove(c);
    }
}
```

But, I get an error on the .OfType :

`'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' could be found.`

Do I need to include something? I'm using .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to include something?....

Yes, you need to include `System.Linq` namespace as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx).